# What is the distribution of the matrix elements for a Poisson distribution of eigenvalue spacing?

Tags: random-matrices

I've already know that entries with normal distribution will give the Wigner-Dyson distribution of eigenvalue spacing, but what about the Poisson distribution of level spacing? What kind of random matrix will produce Poisson distribution of eigenvalue spacing?